# Chocolatey install packages from local network

Tags: chocolatey

Is it possible to install packages from a location on local network or even your own harddrive, because I  dont want my chocolatey script to download the packages from internet everytime I run it. I want to be able to put the packages on to central location from where it picks up the packages.

Let me know if its possible.

Comment: The packages in question, are these Chocolatey packages that you are creating yourself, or are they packages that exist on the Chocolatey Community Feed, that you are going to bring in house?

Comment: Are you asking about having a $url in chocolateyInstall.ps1 mapped to a network path instead of a web url? I would be interested in that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes absolutely possible. Since the first day. Note the image right on https://chocolatey.org even mentions this.